# How can I tell Linux to ignore disk partitions it's already discovered?

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, lvm

I'm running libvirt with QEMU/KVM and I have disk images for the VMs in LVM logical volumes.  Naturally, many of the guest VMs use LVM for their disks, too.

I ran `partprobe` on my hypervisor and it detected all of the VM guest partitions, so now the LVM tools (`pvs`, `vgs`, `lvs`, etc.) list all of the guest's LVM entities along with the host's.

Is there a way to remove all of these LVM physical volumes from the host's knowledge (without affecting the guests, of course)?  Rebooting the host isn't an option; several of these VMs need to stay running.

In case it helps, here's what the LVM layers look like, more or less:

```
/dev/sdb1 - host PV
  |
vg_hostname_vms - host VG
  |
  +-lv_vm1 - host LV, used as a disk image for vm1
  |   +-part1 - vm1 boot partition
  |   +-part2 - vm1 PV
  |       |
  |     vg_vm1 - vm1 VG
  |       +-lv_root - vm1 LV - /
  |       +-lv_swap - vm1 LV - swap
  |
  +-lv_vm2 - host LV, used as a disk image for vm2
      +-part1 - vm1 boot partition
      +-part2 - vm2 PV
          |
        vg_vm2
          +-lv_root - vm2 LV - /
          +-lv_swap - vm2 LV - swap
          +-lv_home - vm2 LV - /home
```

Now, when I run `vgs`, here's what I see:

```
VG              #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
vg_hostname_vms   1   2   0 wz--n- 10.91t 9.53t
vg_vm1            1   2   0 wz--n-  9.76g    0
vg_vm2            1   3   0 wz--n- 97.16g    0
```

I only want to see the host's volume groups (and only its physical and logical volumes).

I'm running all of this on a Scientific Linux 6.5 host.  The guest OSes vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of the guest PVs with the low-level `dmsetup` command.

To remove the device associated with partition 2 on vm1's disk image, run:

```
dmsetup remove /dev/mapper/vg_hostname_vms-lv_vm1p2
```

This will cause vm1's PV, VG, and LVs to disappear from the host's LVM tools.

Answer (score 3):

You should set up an LVM filter on the host, to filter out the unwanted LVM devices detected. Here's a link to the official documentation:

http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/lvm_filters.html

something like `filter = [ "r|/dev/VM_related_VG/*|" ]` should work

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and solved it with an LVM filter defined in the `devices` section of the LVM configuration file `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`:

```
global_filter = [ "a|^/dev/sd|", "a|^/dev/nvme|", "r|.*|" ]
```

In my case I want to allow PVs whose device pathname starts with `/dev/sd` or with `/dev/nvme` and finally reject all the rest.

I have used `global_filter` instead of `filter` in order to make sure the filter applies always.